# No positive real such that $\left\lfloor\frac{25}{x}+\frac{49}{a}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{144}{x+a}-1\right\rfloor$

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Let $a>0$. Prove $\nexists x\in\mathbb R^+$ s.t.
>
> $$\left\lfloor\frac{25}{x}+\frac{49}{a}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{144}{x+a}-1\right\rfloor$$

I know that $$k\in\mathbb Z\implies\left(\forall x\in\mathbb R\right) \lfloor x+k\rfloor=\lfloor x\rfloor + k.$$

I can say that $\left\lfloor\frac{144}{x+a}-1\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{144}{x+a}\right\rfloor-1$.

How should I proceed after this? Does this help in any way?

Comment: use: '\lfloor' & '\rfloor'..

Comment: The expression seems like one has to use CS inequality or more specifically, Titu's Lemma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The floor function, $\lfloor x\rfloor$, is bounded by $x-1< \lfloor x\rfloor\le x$ so you have $\text{RHS}\le \left(\frac{144}{x+a}-1\right)$ and $\left(\frac{25}{x}+\frac{49}{a}\right)-1<\text{LHS}$. By considering their (single) intersection, consider how you can form an inequality with $\left(\frac{144}{x+a}-1\right)$ and $\left(\frac{25}{x}+\frac{49}{a}\right)-1$, then check whether this intersection is a solution and find an inequality relating all four terms.

Comment: A good thing to notice is that $25,49,144$ are all perfect squares so there might appear to be a hidden quadratic equation in the problem.

Comment: Jam, $\frac{5^2}{x}+\frac{7^2}{a} \geq \frac{(5+7)^2}{x+a}$ from Cauchy-Schwarz :)

Comment: @Atticus You can use CS but I think it's just as easy to prove it without it in this case.